# Assert Some with FsUnit

Tags: f#, fsunit

I am trying to check that my function returns `Some(x)`

```
testedFunc() |> should be (sameAs Some)
testedFunc() |> should be Some
testedFunc() |> should equal Some
```

All don't work. I'd rather not use:

```
match testedFunc() with
    | Some -> Pass()
    | None -> Fail()
```

Anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: For comparison using Unquote (http://code.google.com/p/unquote/), see https://gist.github.com/2366849

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't really used FsUnit, but something like this should work...

```
testedFunc() |> Option.isSome |> should equal true
```

Or because an Option already has an IsSome property, you could do this, but be careful of case - it's different from the `Option.isSome` function.

```
testedFunc().IsSome |> should equal true
```

A third approach would be to compose together the function you're testing with `Option.isSome` to get a function that returns boolean directly. This isn't so useful in this example, but if you need to test an Option-returning function several times with a variety of inputs, this approach could help reduce duplicate code.

```
let testedFunc = testedFunc >> Option.isSome
testedFunc() |> should equal true
```